# find if same UIImageView class intersects each other

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimageview

I created a subclass of UIimageView because i want to use this imageview multiple times. I'm using touchesmoved to drag the image. So when i use multiple images of same class, i want to find whether they intersect each other. Here's the image class code

```
 import UIKit

    class imgBall: UIImageView {

        private var xOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
        private var yOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

        required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
            fatalError("use init(point:")
        }


        init(point:CGPoint) {
            let image = UIImage(named: "ball.png")!
            super.init(image:image)

            self.frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
            self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            let point = touches.anyObject()!.locationInView(self.superview)
            xOffset = point.x - self.center.x
            yOffset = point.y - self.center.y

        }

        override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            let point = touches.anyObject()!.locationInView(self.superview)
            self.center.x = point.x - xOffset        
        }
    }
```

and this is how I'm using it in gameviewcontroller

```
viewDidLoad() {

var ball1 = imgBall(point: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 0))
self.view.addSubview(ball1)

var ball2 = imgBall(point: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 70))
self.view.addSubview(ball2)
```

}

so how do i find out if they intersect/collide each other?

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use **CGRectIntersectsRect** with something like this :

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball1.frame,ball2.frame) {
    // they intersect
} else {
    // they're safe
}
```

Comment: that i know, but im not sure where do i have to use this code? in gamevc's touchesmoved or viewdidload OR in imageviewclass?

Comment: You have to use it in touchesMoved because you'll get information of the current finger position. I mean only if the move of the finger of your player does change things.
Otherwise, if both balls (ball1 & ball2) are moving themselves, you've got to use this inside the timer/thread iteration that does the move.

Comment: yes i tried that and touchesmoved is not detecting touch if i touch on the ball, but it detects if i touch anywhere else in the screen.